# Why html sections didn't open

Tags: html, css

I have an html file on my desktop , it has some images and when I click on them I got a section of another page and the url of this page is like : "mysite.html/#section-name " but the problem is when I host this html file the first page is hosted with no problem but when i click on images nothing happened and also when I put mysite.com/#section-name I got just the first page.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: post your code so we can help